# HAProxy 1.5 Serving Static Assets Very Slowly

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I'm doing a few side-by-side comparisons because we'd like to switch from Ngnix as a load balancer to HAProxy. The problem is that when I set up HAProxy I end up getting a really slow load time, specifically when serving static assets. Any ideas off the top as to why this might be happening? I can provide all the redacted config files if needed.

Comment: Yeah, the config files might help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your configuration. But the first thing that comes to my mind is that you are probably running without persistent connections (HTTP keep-alive) on a machine where setting up a connection is extremely slow (eg: improperly tuned firewall enabled on the machine). After that it also depends what you call "very slow" of course. Regular benchmarks on a *real* machine such as a modern Xeon E5 report about 200000 HTTP requests per second per CPU core (HTTP keep-alive, small objects), about 120000 HTTP connections per second per CPU core (HTTP close, small objects) and between 15-20 Gbps per core for large objects (64k+). If you're not within these numbers, probably that some tuning is required, either in the configuration or on the system itself (eg: conntrack hash table size).